# What am I telling you here?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Is appreciating Honest Abe easy for everyone?
He was from Delaware I think.  He was made into an effigy and ridiculed.  But some say he loved a chai tea once in a while.  He had a friend named Jake, a loyal companion.  Jake shared tea with him, but took a lemon in his.  You may wonder why I, the writer, am saying so much nonsense.  This question probably wouldn’t stand out in a lineup.  I guess I’m a rusty puzzler.  Maybe I’ve been exposed to too many ultraviolet rays.  Maybe it was when I came from City Jet airport?  I actually don’t know why, see ya later... oh! Now I know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are giving us

> the alphabet

thus:

> Is appreciating Honest /**A**/**be ea**/**sy**/ for everyone? He was from /**Delaware**/ I think. He was made into an /**eff**/i/**gy**/ and ridiculed. But some say he loved /**a ch**/**ai**/ tea once in a while. He had a friend named /**Ja**/**ke, a**/ loyal companion. Jake shared tea with him, but took /**a l**/**em**/**on**/ in his. You may wonder why /**I, the writer**/, am saying so much nonsense. This /**question**/ probably wouldn’t stand out in a lineup. I guess I’m /**a r**/**us**/**ty**/ puzzler. Maybe I’ve been exposed to too many /**ultraviolet**/ rays. Maybe it was when I came from /**City Jet**/ airport? I actually don’t know /**why**/, /**see**/ ya later... oh! Now I know...

where

> Delaware = DE, I the writer = OP, question = Q, ultraviolet = UV, City Jet = WX. (The most non-obvious of these is the last: WX is the IATA code for the airline called City Jet.)

In fact it turns out

> that Q was intended to be represented by "lineup" (= queue) rather than by "question". I don't see much to choose between those two interpretations...

Comment: The alphabet. That's the gist. A rather simple puzzle.  The remaining letters are more disguised as cryptic clues, synonyms, or acronyms.

Comment: Ah, OK. All filled in, then. I wasn't sure whether I should be looking for something more...

Comment: Great! All except Q :)

Comment: Then I guess kedarguru's answer has the intended identification for Q -- though I confess I don't see why it's better than mine :-).

Comment: Now I know... my ABCs!  You got it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything Gareth said, but solving for Q

> "This question probably wouldn’t stand out in a lineup." What are you describing is a queue (or Q)

I like this one. Very fun puzzle!